# better way of using debugger for someone new to developer tool debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging

im trying to solve a problem to practice recursive backtracking (in javascript), but i get the error 'too much recursion' and its pretty common and i get it all the time , and in most of the times its easy to solve. But this time the problem is big and im new to debugging using the developer tool build in debugger so its really hard to keep along and catch where the error is occuring , since i only know how to use 'step in, step out and step over' . So my question is is there anyway by which i can jump directly where the problem occurs and have all the values stored at that moment using the firefox debugger?

Comment: In Chrome there is a "Pause on exceptions" button, pretty sure there is the same button in Firefox

Comment: yep there is a pause on exeption but it doesnt work for the 'too much recursion' error, idk why

Comment: *"i get it all the time"*  Show us an example of what you are trying to do

Comment: im trying to make a sudoku solver , and i actually did, it solved some boards but didnt solve some other boards (it gives me the 'too much recursion' error),which means that there is an untreated base case. So im trying to know where exactly the program needs that base case by using the debugger,but its soooo long , and it took me more than three hours and i still havnt reached the error.Thats why i asked is there anyway where i can directly jump to were the problem is ( i hope i explained well , cause i think i didnt)